# Django storages amazon S3 giving 400 bad request exception

Tags: django, python-2.7, amazon-s3, boto, django-1.8

This is the first time I was tying to use AWS S3 for media storages. The application is hosted in Heroku, for static files it has not been a problem so I do not want to change static files, but want the applications users to upload files and images which I wish to store in S3. I have already spent 2-3 days so far now and no proper solution was found as I get 400 exception without a proper reason.
Here is the documentation which I referred to:
http://tech.marksblogg.com/file-uploads-amazon-s3-django.html
So, my settings now:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'

AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID='dummyid'
AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='dummykey'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME='dummyname'
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_HEADERS = {'Cache-Control': 'max-age=86400', }
MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
MEDIA_URL = 'http://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/media/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
```

My model:

`class DummyDocuments(models.Model):
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='documents')`

My form:

`class DummyUploadForm(forms.Form):
    documents = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))`

And here is the view, where I am using it:

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DummyUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            files = request.FILES.getlist('documents')
            for file in files:
                instance = DummyDocuments(document=file)
                instance.save()
            return redirect('activation_upload')
    else:
        form = DummyUploadForm()

    documents = DummyDocuments.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'activation/dummyupload.html', {'form': form, 'documents': documents})
```

Here is my CORS config on AWS:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>`

Here is the exception which I am getting:
[image]

May I know what exactly is wrong?

---

### SOLUTION

---

All this django storage libs are quiet undocumented. I went through a lot of different articles to figure this out.
You need this setting:

```
AWS_S3_HOST = 's3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com'
```

and, `~/.boto` config with the contents:

```
[Credentials]
aws_access_key_id=yourid
aws_secret_access_key=yourkey

[s3]

host=s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: Which region are you using?

Comment: @Withnail Asia Pacific (Mumbai), but I saw that it is not needed in the console.

Comment: yeah, was asking as there's an issue with the Frankfurt/London regions - i switched from them to Dublin yesterday having the same issue and it fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is caused (assuming that all of the credentials and other setup are correct, but it's throwing a 400 error rather than a 403) by [this issue](https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/2741).

As a result, the two options seem to be:

1. Switch regions (*as mentioned in comments, I had this problem yesterday with a new install of boto, and switched from London -> Dublin, which rectified it with no further changes*)
2. Add a file ~/.boto and put in the following, per [Martin's](https://github.com/martin3000) comment on that thread.:

   `[s3]`

   `host=s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com`

Substituting for your appropriate region.  You can create the file either by `touch ~/.boto` and editing it from there, or by simply doing `nano ~/.boto` and saving it.

Comment: I deleted and changed it to Montreal region but still the same issue, between where to add ~/.boto config?

Comment: ~ is the home directory of the user that's calling/running the django project. but if you do `nano ~/.boto` it'll *create the file*. 

(substitute your preferred editor for nano)

Comment: Ok, I tried it and created ~/.boto file, but now I am getting this 

`S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 301 Moved Permanently`

Comment: Well, that's a different error.  There are a few answers about how to fix that one. :)  But you may just be able to move back to Mumbai region using the appropriate `.boto` config.

Comment: But it works now, you need to add both AWS_S3_HOST = 's3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com'
and ~/.boto config file. and the value should match the region you have set the bucket to be.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, what worked for me was creating a new bucket in a different region. It seems like the boto package has issues connecting to s3 buckets in specific regions. My settings.py file

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'your-access-key'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'your-secret-access-key'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'mybucketname'
```

No boto file needed when the host region was s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com